# Where to find past url visited on Microsoft edge

Tags: microsoft-edge

Does anyone know how to find past visited url’s in a temp folder after deleting history. I can’t the website I needed for my report. I have done this twice in two days. I just need to find the url. I tried looking at the cache folder and other things but when I open it, it’s just a bunch of jibberish with strange texts

Comment: It’s Microsoft edge btw

Comment: I found it never mind

Comment: You should submit my answer